# Dynamic Linq - no property or field exists in type 'datarow'

Tags: dynamic-linq

I am using Northwind Customers Table where I fill the dataset and get the datatable.

I am trying to use dynamic linq and want to select columnName dynamically

```
var qry = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().Select("new(Country)");
```

Right now I have hard coded country but even then I get this error

```
No property or field 'Country' exists in type 'datarow'
```

I would like to eventually change this query to take the column name dynamically.

Please help!!! thanks.

Comment: You can indicate that Slauma provided the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to his answer.

Answer (score 4):

The important hint is here (in bold):

> No property or field 'Country' exists
>   in **type** 'datarow'

The extension method `AsEnumerable` of the `DataTable` class returns an `IEnumerable<T>` where T has the type `DataRow`. Now the `Select` method of Dynamic LINQ wants to work with this **type** `DataRow` which hasn't a **property** `Country` of course.

You could try this instead:

```
var qry = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
    .Select("new(it[\"Country\"] as CountryAlias)");
```

`it` now represents a variable of type `DataRow` and you can use methods of this type and perhaps also the indexer in my example above. (Dynamic LINQ supports accessing array elements by an integer index, but I am not sure though if accessing an indexer with a string key will work.)

Comment: Thank you very much I just had to use as

Comment: var qry = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
    .Select("new(it[\"Country\"]) as CountryAlias");

Comment: Yes, I've also just seen that `as` is necessary. I'll edit my answer to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Slauma's answer and it worked. In addition i was doing OrderBy with dynamic linq maybe this will help to someone. I'll just drop the code here.

```
string dynamicLinqText = $"it[\"{sortColumnName}\"] {sortDirection}"; //it["PERSON_NAME"] asc
result = result.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(dynamicLinqText).CopyToDataTable();
```