# Dynamic Linq - how do you sort a collection by Enum property alphabetically?

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I have a collection of entities.

One of the properties is an enumeration.

How can I sort the collection alphabetically by its enum name instead of value?

In LINQ it would look like this:

```
var a = collection.OrderBy(x => Enum.GetName(x.OrderType.GetType(), x.OrderType)).ToList();
```

I can't seem to translate this to Dynamic Linq.

I tried to put it directly, but it throws an Exception:

```
collection.OrderBy("x => Enum.GetName(x.OrderType.GetType(), x.OrderType) ascending")
```

Comment: Try get the enum name outside of the dynamic linq and just put `OrderBy($"x => {enumName} asc")`

Comment: Is there a reason you need this to be in dynamic linq? Also, if you say it throws an exception, then you should tell us what that exception is.

Comment: We are researching different libraries for filtering and sorting, to avoid writing it ourselves. OData and Dynamic Linq are among the choices. The Exception message is "Enum type 'Enum' not found" @DavidG

Comment: So instead of `Enum.GetName` use `System.Enum.GetName`?

Comment: @DavidG, just tried it. This time the exception message is: "Enum value 'GetName' is not defined in enum type 'System.Enum'"

Answer (score 1):

For .net framework (not core), see this answer: [Call function in dynamic linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313362/call-function-in-dynamic-linq) which explains that only certain types are available in dynamic linq expressions. Full list of types available in [source code](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/09657b9c097f03c9e426a1554719402e80ba9221/src/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/Parser/PredefinedTypesHelper.cs)

For the dotnet core answer, see the documentation at https://dynamic-linq.net/advanced-configuration . You need to create a custom type provider, than create a parser configuration and use that in your query.

Example below.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.CustomTypeProviders;
                    
public class Program
{   
    public class MyCustomTypeProvider : DefaultDynamicLinqCustomTypeProvider
    {
        public override HashSet<Type> GetCustomTypes() =>
            new[] { typeof(System.Enum), typeof(System.ConsoleColor) }.ToHashSet();
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        // example data source (using primitive data type)
        var listy = new List<System.ConsoleColor>();
        listy.Add(ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
        listy.Add(ConsoleColor.Yellow);
        listy.Add(ConsoleColor.Cyan);
        listy.Add(ConsoleColor.White);

        // regular linq query
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", listy.OrderBy(x => Enum.GetName(x.GetType(), x))));
        
        var config = new ParsingConfig
        {
            CustomTypeProvider = new MyCustomTypeProvider()
        };
        
        // dynamic linq calling Enum method
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", listy.AsQueryable().OrderBy(config, "x => Enum.GetName(x.GetType(), x)")));
    }
}
```

output

```
Cyan, DarkBlue, White, Yellow
Cyan, DarkBlue, White, Yellow
```